# find_package(catkin) fails in Hydro

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to move some packages made in Groovy to Hydro, which I just finished installing. After struggling to convert my previous workspace, I am trying to start again fresh, so following the tutorial I

```
source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
mkdir -p ~/iar_ws_hydro/src
cd ~/iar_ws_hydro/src
cd ~/iar_ws_hydro/
catkin_make
```

However, when I run the `catkin_make` command in my brand new folder, it seems to recognize the command and start setting up the workspace, but then fails to find the catkin package. Here's the output:

```
abouchard@linux-z28r:~/iar_ws_hydro> catkin_make
Base path: /home/abouchard/iar_ws_hydro
Source space: /home/abouchard/iar_ws_hydro/src
Build space: /home/abouchard/iar_ws_hydro/build
Devel space: /home/abouchard/iar_ws_hydro/devel
Install space: /home/abouchard/iar_ws_hydro/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/abouchard/iar_ws_hydro/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/abouchard/iar_ws_hydro/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/abouchard/iar_ws_hydro/install" in "/home/abouchard/iar_ws_hydro/build"
####
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.7.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.7.2
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:44 (message):
  find_package(catkin) failed.  catkin was neither found in the workspace nor
  in the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.  One reason may be that no ROS setup.sh was
  sourced before.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!                                                                                                                 
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

I have to confess to being totally lost on this one. Obviously catkin is installed because it recognizes the catkin_make command, and the setup.bash calls setup.sh. `$CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` contains `/opt/ros/hydro:/home/abouchard/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated`, and I can confirm that there are a whole mess of catkin executables in `/opt/ros/hydro/bin` if that helps.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/96836/find_package(catkin)-fails-in-hydro/) by [teddybouch](https://answers.ros.org/users/581/teddybouch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 320 on 2013-11-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was that I was building locally and manually moving the contents of the install_isolated directory to `/opt/ros/hydro/`, with the result that my paths were not properly configured and packages not properly installed. When I wiped out my installation entirely and rebuilt using the `--install-space` flag, everything worked fine and didn't give any errors.

---

Originally posted by [teddybouch](https://answers.ros.org/users/581/teddybouch/) with karma: 320 on 2013-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't see it in the tutorials anymore, but there's a command (at least there was in groovy) called `catkin_init_workspace` that I was under the impression needed to be run in the overall catkin workspace (not the src folder) before `catkin_make` was run. Things might have changed, but it's worth looking into.

```
$ catkin_init_workspace -h
usage: catkin_init_workspace [-h] [workspace]

Initializes a catkin workspace by creating a top-level CMakeLists.txt.

positional arguments:
  workspace   The path to an existing folder (default: .)

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2013-11-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [teddybouch](https://answers.ros.org/users/581/teddybouch/) on 2013-11-01**:
I figured out what it was, and was able to get it to work without this, so I'm guessing the functionality was moved into the general catkin_make with hydro. Thanks, though!